# Is there a way to find out the count of videos that I've watched on youtube?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I want to find out the count of videos that I've watched on youtube. Is there an easy way to do that ?

Comment: Not any more. It used to be part of the YouTube history, but has been removed.

Comment: This question is way too broad.  What have you tried so far?  What language are you working in?  Have you read the documentation?